# How can I set up an autorun to depend on a certain collection query without actually fetching data?

Tags: meteor

Scenario: I'm calling a method from my template that makes some complex computation using data from several collections and returns one small piece of data. That works fine and it saves bandwidth.

```js
Template.bar.onCreated(function() {
    this.bar = new ReactiveVar();
    Meteor.call("foobar", (err, res) => { if (err) { throw err; } else { this.bar.set(res) }} );
});
```

Now I want to put that method call in an `autorun` so that it re-runs whenever one (just one) of the collections involved changes. The only solution I can come up with would be to just `subscribe` to some very specific publication, and do a `.find({}).fetch()` inside said `autorun`, which would definitely work, but it would also retrieve data that I will not actually use, thus wasting bandwidth and defeating the point.

```js
Template.bar.onCreated(function() {
    this.bar = new ReactiveVar();
    Meteor.subscribe('specificFooDocuments');//TMI :(
    this.autorun(() => {
        Foo.find({}).fetch();
        Meteor.call("foobar", (err, res) => { if (err) { throw err; } else { this.bar.set(res) }} );
    })
});
```

AFAIK the same would happen with `.observe` and `.observeChanges`.

So the question is: can I make an `autorun` depend on a query without fetching actual data, and if so, how? (native meteor preferred)

Comment: A `.find` on the client doesn't fetch any data it doesn't already have (via the subscription). So you can definitely use that. But I would go about this very differently. I would write the logic on the server inside an `observeChanges` handler there, and from that populate/update a collection that is published to the client.

Comment: @ChristianFritz Hold on. A mere subscription already sends data? I thought it merely defined the subset of a collection that you could access with a find, and then if the find did a subset of *that*, it would only then send data, and just what is needed. Or do you mean in case I was already using that subscription for something else?

Comment: @ChristianFritz I like the idea of just making another collection, but I don't think I can go in that direction at this point. And it raises even more questions. Do you by any chance have a link to somewhere that illustrates that pattern?

Comment: yes, once you subscribe, *all* results of that subscription will be sent to the client and kept up to date there as things change in the DB. If you don't want that (and you usually want to be selective) then your publications should probably take arguments that you provide in your `subscribe` call. When these arguments are reactive data sources, then the subscription will update as those values change. Hence only providing what you need at the moment.

Comment: sorry, no, I don't have a link for that off-hand. But I highly recommend getting familiar with `observeChanges` on the server. It is very powerful and also very analogous to reactivity on the client. For that reason it often comes in handy. Once you understand how it works, the rest will be fairly straightforward I think.